# Remove .php extension from the URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to remove .php extension from the URL so that URL like http://mysite.com/abc.php will redirect to http://mysite.com/abc How can I do this using .htaccess in apache

Comment: Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/htaccess-to-remove-php-extension-godaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

You can easily Google it.....